# Status of video uploaded via YouTube Data API is always "processing" (Python)

Tags: python, youtube

I'm using the YouTube Data API (in python) to upload a video. The video uploads successfully, and I get back a YouTubeVideoEntry object. I'm then polling the uploaded video's status as recommended [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python#UploadStatus), but even after the video is done processing (which I verify using the Video Manager dashboard on Youtube.com), CheckUploadStatus continues to return ('processing',''). Here is my code:

```
    upload_status = yt_service.CheckUploadStatus(new_entry)
    state = upload_status[0]

    while state == "processing":
        upload_status = yt_service.CheckUploadStatus(new_entry)
        state = upload_status[0]
        time.sleep(5)
```

This loop never exits, because upload_status[0] is always 'processing'

Comment: Has there ever been an answer?