# Video file is stuck at 0% percent when being uploaded via YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

As the title reads, a video file can be uploaded and processed via YouTube's upload function. However, when I try to upload it programmatically (via OAuth2 and YouTube API v3), it gets always stuck at 0% percent processing. Are there any youtubers on SO? Is there some special forum for upload issues?
(PS, there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575100/status-of-video-uploaded-via-youtube-data-api-is-always-processing-python) with no results.)

**UPDATED ERROR**: Digging deeper, it seems to be related to the video metadata. I do get the following error occasionally:

> Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 400: youtube.video, The
>   request metadata specifies an invalid video title.)

Unfortunately, [the error page for YouTube's API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) does not really suffer from logorrhoea... Does anyone know what the error means?

**UPDATED CODE:**
At the moment the files are uploaded chunk by chunk (which usually works pretty well but not all the times):

```
    function uploadFile($dbfile) {
        $client = $this->client;
        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
        $htmlBody = "";
        try {

            // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
            // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
            // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
            // video category.
            $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
            $snippet->setTitle($dbfile->displayname);
            // Numeric video category. See
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
            $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

            // Set the video's status to "private"
            $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
            $status->privacyStatus = "private";

            // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
            $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
            $video->setSnippet($snippet);
            $video->setStatus($status);

            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            $client->setDefer(true);

            $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

            // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                $client,
                $insertRequest,
                'video/*',
                null,
                true,
                $chunkSizeBytes
            );
            $media->setFileSize(filesize($dbfile->localfile));

            // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
            $status = false;
            $handle = fopen($dbfile->localfile, "rb");
            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
              $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
              $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            }

            fclose($handle);
            $client->setDefer(false);

            $log = array("success" => true, "snippet_id" => $status["id"]);
        } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
            $log = array("success" => false, "errormsg" => $e->getMessage());
        } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
            $log = array("success" => false, "errormsg" => $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $log;
    }
```

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How exactly are you doing this programmatically?

Comment: I have updated the question and attached the code in question.

Comment: Is your internet connection stable? You might want to set `chunkSizeBytes` lower for better recovery on less reliable connections. Other than that, the only other place I can think of where it might be having problems is when you set the file size. Have you tried debugging to get a better idea of where it's messing up?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Well, indeed, it is (we do have a 250mbit backbone). Nevertheless, I will try and reduce the chunk size.

Comment: Is it really not uploading or are you just not getting progress updates? The latter also is a common problem when uploading via the usual YT user interface. You may want to insert some debug output into your `while()` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well then, there might be other issues with videos not being processed but mine was that the title of the video to be inserted was simply too long. YouTube has a limitation of **no more than 100 characters**. If you try to insert longer video titles, it throws the above exception. Perhaps they should note this somewhere in their API documentation.